# ssis export from excel

Tags: ssis

I'm using ssis to export from Excel to text. Everything exports fine except one column has data in this format `0X906111` but is `null` when exporting.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Is it coming into your data flow as null, or being lost on the output?  Try adding a data viewer (from the data flow line) to view the input.

If the data is coming in as null, try changing the Excel column type.

If the data is coming in okay, but not being exported correctly, use the data conversion control in ssis to set the data type accordingly.